# Is it possible to point a specific port from a domain name?

Tags: subdomain

Basically what I want is this:

first.name.com:25565 -> 127.0.0.1:25562 
second.name.com:25565 -> 127.0.0.1:25565

This is for some minecraft server's I'm hosting.

Comment: I could be just using the wrong search terms, I don't exacly know what I'm doing at this point. I know an easier solution would be to have multiple public IP addresses

Comment: the wrod 'redirect' is not clear. please add your steps to verify whether something is redirected or not.  and maybe something similiar to **ssh port forward**, or **nginx reverse proxy**?

Comment: Proxy would be a better word, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's what I ended up doing:

mc.name.com is pointed at the server's hostname using a CNAME record

The next record I added was an SRV record to make 25565 point at 25562 (or whatever port I need it to be)

`_minecraft._tcp.mc.muchieman.com` `SRV` `900` `0 5 25562 mc.muchieman.com.`

900 being TLS, 0 being priority, 5 being weight, 25562 being the port to point to

Comment: this is nothing reverse proxy at all. it's just basic dns settings. all is related to your own server. in think the question should be `how to setup sub domain dns to point to different ports on server`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Name-based virtual hosting. At the layer 4 transport, you can only redirect to different services by IP or port number, however, a number of protocols including HTTP(S) transmit the domain name used in the request and this allows a reverse proxy service such as Apache or Nginx to redirect to the actual service on the same or even a different host. Squid is normally used as a forward proxy on the client side which is not helpful in this case. What you want is a reverse HTTP(S) proxy on the server side. I am most familiar with Apache so I will present that here, but Nginx and others can do it as well. You will need the name-based virtual hosting of Apache to create a different service per hostname and then reverse proxy it to the real service behind it. As a note, you can't both have Apache running on 1234 and

```
Listen 10.1.1.1:1234
NameVirtualHost 10.1.1.1:1234

<VirtualHost 10.1.1.1:1234>
    ServerName first.name.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:4321/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:4321/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.1.1.1:1234>
    ServerName second.name.com:1234
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:1234/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:1234/"
</VirtualHost>
```

You also need to make sure that the mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http modules are enabled for Apache. On Debian/Ubuntu, this can be done with this:

```
$ sudo a2enmod proxy
$ sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

And the final note, you asked for the same port from the proxy, 1234, to be redirected to the local host on 127.0.0.1. Normally, I would recommend using a different port for the actual service, but you can share the port if to bind Apache to the external IP explicitly as I did in the example above using 10.1.1.1, and then bind the internal service only to 127.0.0.1. If you use the normal wildcard binding which it written as either 0.0.0.0 or *, then the two services will conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I definitely should've included more in my initial question. I have tried apache like you've shown, but it doesn't seem to work. I assume it's because it's just because it only works for http and not anything else, but I really don't know - this is at the point where it's getting hard for me to understand. It's for a Minecraft server, which I also should've included in the initial question

Comment: you have to at least know which protocal the upstream server is using. for example, http, https, or just tcp? and i also want to know in your example, is `first.name.com` owned by you or not? if you just want to proxy some external https endpoints to local, it might not work due to certificate issue.

Comment: I do own the domain name that I'm trying to use, and I'd like to proxy tcp/udp, I don't think I need to proxy http/s